# Adicionar N items a uma Textbox baseado num NumericUpDown

Tags: c#

Criei um programa que gera *passwords*, mas apenas gera uma de cada vez.

O que eu queria era poder disponibilizar um `NumericUpDown` para que o utilizador pudesse escolher quantas *passwords* quer, que depois seriam apresentadas numa `Textbox`.

Como posso fazer isso?

O código do meu botão é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: e qual o problema?

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade o problema é que não sei o código para fazer isso. Já procurei, e não encontro.

Comment: use um combobox(dropdownlist não sei como tu conhece) com a quantidade de número, ai depois tu só verifica qual a quantidade escolhida e executa a função n vezes.

Comment: Amigo @Marciano.Andrade eu conheço a Dropdownlist, porém não sei qual o código que tenho que usar. Pode-me ajudar?

Comment: Ok, posso sim, já formulo uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado amigo @Marciano.Andrade , ficarei a aguardar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazê-lo da seguinte forma:

```
// No clique de um botão, ou num outro evento que queira
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove as passwords que existirem na ListBox (caso as deseja manter remova a linha seguinte.
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    // Loop ate ao numero seleccionado no numericupdown 
    for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; ++i)
    {
        // A cada iteraccao gere uma password nova
        var password = //seu código de gerar passwords;

        // Por fim adicione a nova password a ListBox.
        listBox1.Items.Add(password);
    }
}
```

O resultado final será (usando `GUIDs` como *passwords*):

[image: Gerar N passwords para uma ListBox]

Edit:

Tendo em conta o seu caso especifico:

```
if(...)
{
}
else
{
    CopyButton.Enabled = true;
    SaveButton.Enabled = true;

    // Modifique aqui para o seguinte codigo
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    // Loop ate ao numero seleccionado no numericupdown 
    for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; ++i)
    {
        // A cada iteraccao gere uma password nova
        var password = Generator.GetRandomPassword(Convert.ToInt32(PasswordLengthList.Value), GetStringTemplate());

        // Por fim adicione a nova password a ListBox.
        listBox1.Items.Add(password);
    }
}
```

Da forma como tem actualmente esta a imprimir a password gerada para uma `textbox`. Tem de adicionar uma `listbox` e usar o código acima.

Comment: Amigo @Omni, eu já tenho o código para gerar password's, mas só está para criar 1 sempre que se toca no button. O que eu pretendo é: Se o utliziador quer 2 passwords, selecciona num NumericUpDown "2", carrega no button, e na textbox aparecem então 2 passwords.

Comment: Coloque o código que esta no evento clique do seu botão.

Comment: Já está amigo, vê se entendes.

Comment: Editei a resposta com o seu caso especifico.

Comment: Assim não está a fazer nada amigo... Para que é o "var password" se já tenho o código para gerar password? Quer que lhe envie o projecto?

Comment: Nao esta a entender, leia o comentario a frente de `var password =`. Troque esse `var password` pelo seu codigo de gerar passwords.

Comment: Perfeito amigo @omni! Então e em vez de Listbox, se for Textbox?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23013/discussion-between-godfathersantana-and-omni).